# PUBNUB - Subscribe doesn't work with .NET Windows services

Tags: c#, pubnub

I'm using following code to subscribe to a channel. It's working fine when I try it on a .NET Console App but when I try the same code in a .NET windows service App, then it doesn't work (doesn't hit delegate (Pubnub pnObj, PNStatus status)). Is there anything else I need to add when building a windows service?

```
private void SubscribeToPubNub()
{
    PNConfiguration pnConfig = new PNConfiguration();
    pnConfig.SubscribeKey = RmmConnection.pNubSub;
    pnConfig.PublishKey = RmmConnection.pNubSubPub;
    pnConfig.Uuid = ConfigManager.GetUUID();

    Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(pnConfig);
    
    SubscribeCallbackExt mySubscribeListener = new SubscribeCallbackExt(
        delegate (Pubnub pnObj, PNMessageResult<object> message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pubnub.JsonPluggableLibrary.SerializeToJsonString(message));   

        },
        delegate (Pubnub pnObj, PNPresenceEventResult presence)
        {
            if (presence != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pubnub.JsonPluggableLibrary.SerializeToJsonString(presence));
            }
        },
        delegate (Pubnub pnObj, PNStatus status)
        {
            
            if (status != null && status.StatusCode == 200 && status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory)
            {                        
                //connected
            }

        });

    pubnub.AddListener(mySubscribeListener);

    pubnub.Subscribe<string>()
        .Channels(new string[] { "rmm_channel" })
        //.Channels(new string[] { RmmConnection.pNubChannel })
        .WithPresence()
        .Execute();
}
```

Comment: I suspect maybe a system permissions issue in Windows? Is it running as Admin? Is it able to run "all the time"?  We do have customers running as a windows service, so we know it works. Perhaps you can enable logging in the PN C# SDK. That should reveal any errors/exceptions you might be getting.

Comment: @CraigConover It's running under the 'Local System' account and yes it runs all the time. By "enable logging in the PN C# SDK" did you mean the 'Debug Console' on the admin portal? If yes, I already did that but nothing gets logged there. Happens only for the windows service. Are you able to see any specific error logs on your side if I gave you my PUBNUB user name?

Comment: We can see your system logs on our end. We do server log searches for paid accounts or those onboarding to paid account. But I was talking about client side SDK logs: See https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/c-sharp/troubleshooting for details.